# GoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback is not called

Tags: android, dictionary, location, android-mapview

I want to get location with using googleMap and geocode features. Place  find my right latitude,longitude, formatted address. `onMapReady` function is called but `onMapLoaded` function is not called at all.

Manifest:

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="..." />
```

My google gms versions:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
```

My customMapView layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
       android:id="@+id/map_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/address_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="0"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:visibility="visible"
       tools:text="21 Jump St, Atlanta GA 30311" />
</merge>
```

CustomMapView.java:

```
    public class CustomMapView extends LinearLayout {

    private MapView mapView;
    private TextView textView;

    public CustomMapView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.map_view, this, true);

        this.mapView = ViewUtil.findById(this, R.id.map_view);
        this.textView = ViewUtil.findById(this, R.id.address_view);
    }

    public void display(Place place) {

        this.mapView.onCreate(null);
        this.mapView.onResume();

        this.mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        this.mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final @Nonnull GoogleMap googleMap) {

                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLong(), 13));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLong()));
                googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLong(), googleMap.getMaxZoomLevel() - 4));

                googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {

                        googleMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {

                               // it is not called
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        this.textView.setText(place.getDescription());

    }

}
```

Comment: There are `onStart`, `onStop`, ... and many more methods of the `MapView` that you need to manually call from the activity to let the map fully operate. And don't call `MapView.onResume()` after `onCreate`, do it in the right place of activity lifecycle

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: I still don't see you call the MapView.onStart and MapView.onResume in the right place. It has to be called in the same lifecycle as the Activity. See more here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView. In here you put the `MapView` inside a custom LinearLayout, so you have to create all the lifecycle methods inside this custom View and pass the call to the `MapView`. The way you call `onCreate(null)` and `onResume` here is not how it supposes to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, You haven't called right lifecycle methods of the `MapView`. It's already explained in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)

**You custom `View`:**

```
public class CustomMapView extends LinearLayout {

private MapView mapView;
private TextView textView;

public CustomMapView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize(context);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
    mapView.onCreate(var1);
}

public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
}

public void onPause() {
    mapView.onPause();
}

public void onStart() {
    mapView.onStart();
}

public void onStop() {
    mapView.onStop();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

public void onLowMemory() {
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle var1) {
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(var1);
}

private void initialize(Context context) {
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.map_view, this, true);

    this.mapView = ViewUtil.findById(this, R.id.map_view);
    this.textView = ViewUtil.findById(this, R.id.address_view);
}

public void display(Place place) {
    this.mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    this.mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final @Nonnull GoogleMap googleMap) {

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLong(), 13));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLong()));
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLong(), googleMap.getMaxZoomLevel() - 4));

            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {

                    googleMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {

                            // it is not called
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    this.textView.setText(place.getDescription());
}
```

**Your Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private CustomMapView customView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
        super.onCreate(var1);

        customView = ViewUtil.findById(this, R.id.custom_view_id);
        customView.onCreate(var1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        customView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        customView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        customView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        customView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        customView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        customView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle var1) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(var1);
        customView.onSaveInstanceState(var1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the map and the markers shown up? I will check on my side and notify you later

Comment: Yes the map is shown my code and your code. But my problem is that not called `setOnMapLoadedCallback` function. I'm in a lot of trouble please help me.

Comment: The document said: "This event will not fire if the map never loads due to connectivity issues, or if the map is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.". So do your connection is good, and you do any gesture on it while waiting for the event?

Comment: I am waiting for it without touching it at all and my connection at wifi

Comment: One last shot I can give for now: Try to move the call `googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback` to be the first line in `onMapReady`, before `moveCamera` call.

Comment: Very thanks but not working .I wonder that your code goes into the setOnMapLoadedCallback function

Comment: Yes it works on my side, i currently use `MapFragment` so don't have to due with the lifecycle callbacks. I set OnMapLoad first in OnMapReady, only takes ~3s and onLoad is fired.

Comment: Do you mean the project i sent you still not working on your side?

Comment: Yes, I tested it, did you kept the google-service-map lib version the same or you use the latest one?

Comment: How did you get your geocode api key? Is this the right site : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro

Comment: Create an api key in the console, restrict it with my app's package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint, Enable Google Map SDK api and done. Check your Logcat, it will show some red lines error if the key is invalid

Comment: please answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413236/how-can-i-get-location-place-snapshot

Answer (score 0):

I just had a situation with the same symptoms, but a totally different cause. I have a reusable MapFragment that contains my Google map. The fragment worked well for most activities, but onMapLoaded was not called for one particular activity.

It turns out that the "bad" activity layout produced a fragment layout with 0 height. Google maps called onMapReady, but because there was no room to display the map, it (correctly) did not waste a call to onMapLoaded. Changing the activity layout for the map fragment from

> ```
> <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
>   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
>   android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_above"
>   ...
> />
> ```

to

> ```
> <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
>   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
>   android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
>   android:layout_height="0dp"
>   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_above"
>   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>   ...
> />
> ```

fixed the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33877154)

Comment: Sheesh - if you want to be be that pedantic (characterized by a narrow, often ostentatious concern for formal rules; marked by a narrow focus on or display of learning especially its trivial aspects), I will point out that the OP never formally asked a question. Other answers addressed the implied question - "why does this code not work?" I answered an implied question with a broader scope - "under what circumstances might onMapReady be called, but not onMapLoaded?"

I directly addressed the title: "GoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback is not called."